# Shutdown Mac via network command

Tags: ios, macos, shutdown

I am using an old Mac Mini as a music server and I have written a remote control app for my iOs devices (iPad and iPod). I'm trying to add a button to my remote control app that will send a command to the Mac Mini to shut it down. All queries to doing this talk about remoting into the Mac or using terminal to send a shutdown command. Is there any way I can send an xml sequence or other command over the network that will shut the Mac down?

Comment: If you could just do such a thing it would be an enormous security vulnerability.  You will either need to run some code on your Mac that your app can talk to and have that code execute the shutdown command or you will need to use something like ssh in your app to connect to your Mac and shut it down

Comment: I'm not too concerned about security since it is running on the LAN in my home. I don't expect to access it outside the LAN. I had considered the solution you mention but was hoping that I could do it using AppleScript or something of that sort that was already running on the Mac.

Comment: You will need to run something on the Mac to listen to your incoming request. You aren't concerned about security but Apple and many other users are, so that is why their can't be a simple way to just shut down a Mac remotely. Probably the simplest would be to find an SSH client library for iOS and then you could have your app ssh to your Mac and issue the shutdown command.